# Output of ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings

Tags: vb.net, file-io

My company's pipeline is a vb script written by a guy who left a few months before I was hired as an intern. The pipeline still works, but now nobody knows which machine holds which files, until the files leave the pipeline. Ideally, I could just look for the file names referenced in the vb, but there are two problems:

1. Unfortunately, I have little to no knowledge of vb beyond what any programmer could learn in about a day of reading someone else's vb script.
2. He names his files using trees: he would name files by appending string literals and string variables; every constant was defined by further string literals and string variables. Here's an example branch:

---

```
Private _bax As String = ""
...
_bax = GetAppConfigValue("bax")
Public bar As String = ""
...
.bar = Path.Combine(_bax, "qux")
Dim fileName As String = foo.bar

Function GetAppConfigValue(ByVal key As String) As String
Dim sValue As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings(key)
If sValue Is Nothing Then sValue = ""
Return sValue
End Function
```

My problem is line 2 (admittedly I don't know what the "." preceding bar does in line 4, but that's a separate question). When I first started looking, I hoped that at the end of the branch I would find a file name, but instead I got this. It ends up almost every leaf shares the same syntax when it is assigned:`_variableNameHere = GetAppConfigValue("variableNameHere")`, so actual file names are almost never used. What is the output of GetAppConfigValue("bax") and how does that work as a pathname? is "bax" just a string literal? or does it refer to _bax some how? Ideally, is there a way for me to find the value of _bax without having to run the code (simulating is not really necessary and would be more trouble than just following the tree's by hand, as there are only a few really necessary locations)? Honestly, just figuring out what "bax" referred to would be a big help

A few final notes:

1. Yes, I know ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings is obsolete. But the pipeline works, even if we don't know how, and is brittle and can't risk braking it, so no one edits it.
2. There is a Sub directly above the function, both of which are in the same Region, that initializes a hash table, but, having just begun vb, I'm unsure if the function references to the hash table or not. If turns out that the hash table is important, just ask and I can post it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That first block is very, very problematic.  Is it something you synthesized from different parts?   It is illegal code on several levels

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah, it's grabbed from many different areas of the program. In the actual program, each line from the first block are a few hundred lines apart and in different functions and Regions, etc, so the lines had to be rearranged into what I hope is the right order. But when it comes to the individual lines themselves, other than renaming the variables, I haven't changed much. Is there anything in particular that is problematic in a specific line?

Comment: We usually use `...` to indicate that in examples (see Edit).  I'll bet `.bar` is inside a With block, so that answers that.  As for the rest, I'd set breakpoints at spots you have questions about and drill into procedures to *see* what they do and what they return.  Use the immediate window to poll variables etc.

Comment: @Plutonix One of my problems, is that I can't edit the code. Firstly, because the code is really delicate, and even if we could restore it, checking it would mean sending data though it, which takes hours (and we don't know where to put the data to simulate it). Secondly, because I'm an intern, and a new one at that. And your right about `.bar`, it's in a forever loop waiting for data to be placed, then it goes from there, but what does that answer? Apologies if I'm being obtuse, I just don't know much vb.

Comment: `I don't know what the "." preceding bar does in line 4`.  Even if you cant change or fix anything, you can set breakpoints and learn what it does the next time it is running.  There are some things you just are not going to be able to tell by looking at the code (I'm doing the same thing with 10,000 lines of C# code someone else wrote).

Comment: @Plutonix I get that it is an answer, but is it that any variable in a loop starts with a "." or is it only loop blocks? Or is it just that if a variable starts with a "." it's in a loop? The breakpoint idea seems good, I'm just going to have to justify it to my ?boss? (not sure if that's the exact right word for an actual employee when you're just an intern, but it'll do). Thanks, and good luck with the C#.

Comment: no, `bar` is a property or public member of something like maybe `foo`.  So, rather than writing Foo.Bar (or something much wordier), VB supports `With` blocks: `With Foo // .Bar = "ziggy" // End With` if you have many things to set, it prevents having to type it over and over.